Confirmation of approach for conditional probability question
I'm looking for confirmation regarding my approach for this probability question:
Half the people outside wear black socks, one third wear white, and one sixth are wearing red. What's the probability you see a person wearing black shoes before you see one wearing white?
Approach
Say $P($see black before white$) = p$
Then, doing a simple first-step analysis gives the following,
$p = P($see black$)P($see black before white|see black$) + P($see red$)P($see black before white|see red$) + P($see white$)P($see black before white|see white$)$
The last term is 0. Then $p = \frac{1}{2}\cdot{1} + \frac{1}{6}p = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6}p$
This is because if we see a person with red shoes, then we can effectively say the scenario is starting over again - we have just walked out for the first time, because seeing a person with red shoes doesn't get us any closer to ending our game.
This gives $p = \frac{3}{5}$

Typo alert : Your posted question confuses shoes with socks.

Yes.  That is the correct answer and your recursion argument is valid.

Also, to confirm your answer:
The probability that the first person you meet without red socks will have black socks rather than white is:
$$\mathsf P(B\mid B\cup W)=\dfrac{1/2}{1/2+1/3}=\dfrac{3}{5}$$
